# Form input using Redux Form not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

My input field is not updating on key press:

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class CitySelector extends Component {
  render() {
    const { isFetching, pristine, submitting, handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className="form-horizontal col-xs-offset-1" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.fetchWeather)}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <Field name="city"
                   component={city =>
                     <input type="text" className="form-control" {...city.input} placeholder="enter a city for a 5 day forecast"/>
                   }
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'cityForm'
})(CitySelector);
```

Do I need to supply an `onChange` handler for text inputs?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I was having the same problem and my mistake was very simple.

Here's what I had:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as forms } from 'redux-form';

import otherReducer from './otherReducer';

export default combineReducers({ otherReducer, forms });
```

Notice that I was importing redux-form reducer as `forms` and passing it as is to my combineReducers (like I did with `otherReducer`) using ES6 Object property value shorthand.

The problem is that the **key** used to pass **redux-form reducer** to our combineReducers **MUST** be named **form**, so we have to change it to:

```
export default combineReducers({ customer, form: forms });
```

or

```
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form';
export default combineReducers({ otherReducer, form });
```

Hope this helps someone else...

Comment: nice catch on the key bit

Comment: The docs need to have this information. Doing the 'get started' guide leads you right into the trap. This is the fix.

Comment: I really forget this 'import { reducer as forms } from 'redux-form';

Answer (score 27):

If you are using immutable data structures, instead of:

`import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';`

use this:

`import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';`

See here for more info http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/immutable/

Comment: Thanks, I wasted a few hours wondering why my inputs were not updating!

Comment: thanks, this was what was going on wrong with me. if you happen to use `react-boilerplate`, you would have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was just having an issue similar to this question, except my form wasn't submitting and my validate function also wasn't firing.

It was due to this:

> I changed it from `input` to something else and it totally broke redux-form SILENTLY

```
const TextInput = ({
    input,                                                 <--- DO NOT CHANGE THIS
    placeholder,
    type,
    meta: { touched, error, warning }
  }) => {
    return (
      <div className="row-md">
          <input
            placeholder={placeholder}
            type={type}
            className="form-text-input primary-border"
            {...input}                                     <--- OR THIS
          />
          {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Here's the rest of my input if anyone wants to study it:

```
<Field
  component={TextInput}
  type="tel"
  name="person_tel"
  placeholder="Mobile Phone Number"
  value={this.props.person_tel}
  onChange={(value) => this.props.updateField({ prop: 'person_tel', value })}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you supply a custom input component to the `Field`, then yes you have to call `onChange` passed within `input` prop to your component. In fact, you almost got it right by spreading `city.input`, but there's a catch.

When you define a stateless component (or just any function) **inside** `render()` method, it is recreated upon every render. And because this stateless component is passed as a prop (`component`) to `Field`, it forces `Field` to render after each recreation. So, your input is going to lose focus whenever `CitySelector` component renders, thus, no key presses will be captured.

You should extract your stateless component into a separate definition:

```js
const myInput = ({ input }) => (
  <input type="text" className="form-control" {...input} placeholder="enter a city for a 5 day forecast" />
);

class CitySelector extends Component {
  render() {
    const { isFetching, pristine, submitting, handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className="form-horizontal col-xs-offset-1" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.fetchWeather)}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <Field name="city" component={myInput} />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

It also makes your code more legible.

You can find more info on that problem in [official docs](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/api/Field.md/#usage) of Redux Form. Note that you could probably use the default `input` without creating your own, take a look at [simple form example](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/simple).

Comment: Does my reducer need to update a property called city?

Comment: Well, no, Redux Form manages state updates on its own. I can't really find the source of your problem here. Can you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console and I can see this action getting logged:

 action Object {type: "redux-form/CHANGE", meta: Object, payload: "a"}

Comment: I would not have thought I need to handle redux-form/CHANGE

Comment: If I type a repeatedly I just get the same action with only 1 letter in the payload which would suggest the store is not getting updated correctly

Comment: I was using immutablejs and I had not used the correct reducer etc.

Following the immutablejs example fixed the problem.   Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, I see. But anyway you **shouldn't handle** `redux-form/CHANGE` events on your own. Redux Form already does that!

Just to let others know, in case Immutable.js is used you should import `reduxForm` from `redux-form/immutable`. Everything else with your form stays the same. Here's the [link to an example](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/immutable/).

Comment: I'm not, with the correct reducer and hoc it all works now

Comment: you can put it under a different key as well, but when you call reduxForm(...) you need to pass an option.  e.g. `reduxForm({ ..., getFormState: state => state.forms })`

Answer (score 0):

I found out/ my problem was my

```
form: formReducer
```

was not in rootReducer.

formReducer must be on top. My case:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   general: generalReducer,
   data: combineReducers({
       user:userReducer,
       todoReducer
   }),
       form: formReducer
   });
```